# Changes to a dependent csx file don't take effect until app restart

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

When I edit in App Service Editor a csx file that gets loaded (#load) into my run.csx, the Azure Function isn't being notified of the change. When the function is invoked, it reports a compile error of the edited file. I have to restart the app service before my edits will be used in the compilation process. Surely there's a better way than a restart! If so, what is it?

Note: a restart does force a recompile of the edited files.

Pardon if this is a repeat report of this issue. I thought I has posted it to StackOverflow before but I didn't see it in my history.

Comment: Are you sure it's related to App Service Editor, and not something you'd see equally when modifying the file by *any* mean (FTP, Kudu, ...)?

Comment: Actually I don't believe that it's related to App Service Editor. It probably would occur via the means you specified. I'm just giving one example where I observe the issue.

Comment: I'd suggest rewording the question accordingly, as the current title and wording are misleading. e.g. title should be more like "Changes to a dependent csx file don't take effect until app restart"

Comment: Where is the .csx file located? I attempted a repro and the changes are picked up if the csx file is within the function directory. It's possible you may be using a shared code directory which is not being watched.

Comment: The .csx file is on that is shared across several functions, so it is not within the function directory. I would assume that any code changes would trigger a recompile. If not, is there a way to do so without recycling the app service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For shared source files that are outside of the function directory (which is watched for changes by default) you can indicate that the directory should be watched by adding it to the `watchDirectories` array in your `host.json` file. For example, if your shared directory is named "Shared", you would use:

```
{
    "watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ]
}
```

The [sample app](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/tree/dev/sample) in our repo gives an example of this. See the `host.json` file there, and the corresponding "Shared" folder that contains shared .csx files that are used in various functions.